# UPDATE полей в DRF

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

Здравствуйте!
У меня есть сериализатор вида:

```
class MySerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('address',)
```

Есть ViewSet:

```
class MyViewSet(GenericViewSet, CreateModelMixin, ListModelMixin):
    http_method_names = ['post']
    queryset = MyModel.objects
    serializer_class = MySerializer
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли каким-нибудь образом при получении POST запроса изменить какую либо уже существующую строку в БД? То есть фактически не вызывая метода MyViewSet().create().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

можно переопределить метод def perform_create(self, serializer) во ViewSet. В данном методе изначально вызывается метод serializer.save(). Переопределив perform_create просто не вызываем save(), а просто делаем update() модели